# Why sudo doesn't work when I change my password?

Tags: 14.04, server, sudo, password

After changing my password through command `passwd`, I can't use `sudo`. When I use `sudo -i` for example, it stops and don't ask for my new password.

Comment: Have you added your user to the sudoers file?

Comment: I never edited the sudoers file, so since mine is the only user, I guess it would be a sudoer by default (correct me if I'm wrong). Even if I'm not on sudoers, shouldn't the command give me some output?